# Regular expression to extract the year from a string

Tags: regex

This should be simple but i cant seem to get it going. The purpose of it is to extract v3 tags from mp3 file names in Mp3tag.

I have these strings I want to extract the year.

```
Test String 1 (1994) -> extract 1994
34 Test String 2 (1995)" -> extract 1995
Test (String) 3 (1996)" -> extract 1996
```

I had `^(.+)\s\(([0-9]*)\)$` but obviously its not giving me the results i was expecting. You can say that im not very good with regular expressions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use something like this `\((\d{4})\)$`. The first group will have your match.

**Explanation**

```
\(       # Match the character “(” literally
(        # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d       # Match a single digit 0..9
      {4}      # Exactly 4 times
)
\)       # Match the character “)” literally
$        # Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character)
```

Answer (score 21):

A suggestion for a more generic solution, not sure if that is what you need.  Valid years will always have the form 19xx or 20xx, and the years will be separated with a word-break character (something other than a number or a letter):

```
\b(19|20)\d{2}\b
```

This doesn't really care where in the tag the year appears.  A simpler version that doesn't assume anything more than 4 digits in the year would be this expression:

```
\b\d{4}\b
```

The key here is the **\b** escape sequence, which matches any non-word character (word charaters are letters, digits and underscores), including parenthesis, of course.

Would also like to recommend this site:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the parentheses. Also you can restrict that a year has only got 4 numbers:

```
^(.+)\s\(([0-9]{4})\)$
```

The year is in matchgroup 2.

Comment: whoops it seems i forgot to add the escapes. mmm looks like Mp3tag didnt recognize it :'(.

Comment: Why store the start of the string in a group when it's not required?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: how can you not store it?

Comment: I don't store it in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110077/regular-expression-to-extract-the-year-from-a-string/8110117#8110117).

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with

```
^(.*)\s\(([0-9]{4})\)$
```

(assuming all years have 4 digits, use `[0-9]+` if you have an unknown number of digits, but at least one, or `[0-9]*` if there could be no digits)

Comment: Why do you store the start of the string in a group when it's not needed?

Comment: Because that's what the original question also has.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there with your regular expression.

What you really need is:

```
\s\((\d{4})\)$
```

Where:

- `\s` is some whitespace
- `\(` is a literal '('
- `(` is the start of the match group
- `\d` is a digit
- `{4}` means four of the previous atom (i.e. four digits)
- `)` is the end of the match group
- `\)` is a literal ')'
- `$` is the end of the string

For best results, put into a function:

```
>>> def get_year(name):
...     return re.search('\s\((\d{4})\)$', name).groups()[0]
... 
>>> for name in "Test String 1 (1994)", "34 Test String 2 (1995)", "Test (String) 3 (1996)":
...     print get_year(name)
... 
1994
1995
1996
```