# How to check if the number has 4 digital

Tags: php, preg-match, isnumeric

lets say i have this following value and i want to have the years

```
July 1967 USA
14 March 1979 France
23 June 1976 France
from the 21 October 2016
```

let say this value is `$year2` i am using `is_numeric` but is not give the correct result like always is there away to use `preg_replace`

```
            $year2 = explode(" ",$year1);
            if (!is_numeric($year2[2])) {

                if ( ! isset($year2[1])) {
                 $year2[1] = null;
                 }
            $year =  $year2[1];
            } else {
                 if ( ! isset($year2[2])) {
                 $year2[2] = null;
                 }
                $year =  $year2[2];
                }
            }

echo $year;
```

the outputs sometimes is the day ex: 21 instead of the years 2016
i have try this without success `$year = preg_match('/\d{4}/g',$year2);`

Comment: i would recommend using regex

Comment: how to do that please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to extract the year from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110077/regular-expression-to-extract-the-year-from-a-string)

Comment: It will be helpful : http://www.regextester.com/?fam=96029

Comment: You tagged your question with `preg_match`, did you take the time to read a regex tutorial at least?

Comment: you have had help already by these helpful guys use both links and problem will be solved

Comment: yes i have try preg_match i am not very expert in regex

Comment: In this case you *must* show your attempts in the question, otherwise your question seems like a request without any attempts that is a good reason to close the question as *off-topic*.

Comment: I have try this  $year = preg_match('/\d{4}/g',$year1); but is not working

Comment: Good, you are near the solution, you only need to take a look at `preg_match` in the php manual to see how it works *(match results aren't returned the way you think)*. Other thing the `g` modifier doesn't exists in PHP, to perform a global research you need to use `preg_match_all`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get year from each line (as I understood your question), you can use `preg_match()`

```
<?php

$values = [
    'July 1967 USA',
    '14 March 1979 France',
    '23 June 1976 France',
    'from the 21 October 2016',  
];
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $pattern = '/(^|\s)(\d{4})(\s|$)/m';
    preg_match($pattern, $value, $match);
    echo $match[2] . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1967
1979
1976
2016
```